# Can someone tell me how to install reaver-wps?

Tags: installation, install-from-source

Here is the webpage http://code.google.com/p/reaver-wps/

Can someone help me install it so I can play around with it?

Comment: I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install libpcap*-dev first:

- `sudo apt-get install libpcap*-dev`

Extract the tar file, then from the terminal:

```
cd /path/to/src
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Any ideas about this: E: Unable to locate package lsqlite3
?

Comment: never mind figured it out.

Answer (score 7):

Even if you receive this error during "./configure":

```
error: pcap library not found!
```

installing libsqlite3-dev helps to solve it.

Comment: I've installed libpcap and it is still showing me the error. Installing `libsqlite3-dev` worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you receive the "error: sqlite3 library not found!" then run the following prior to configure:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

if permission is denied when using `./configure` try `sudo sh ./configure`

Comment: -1 `./configure` shouldn't require super-user privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Before running ./configure, I needed to install a few libraries in Ubuntu 12.04. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3 libsqlite3-dev libpcap-dev
```